# How to manage a YouTube account's playlist automatically

Tags: c#, youtube, google-api-client, youtube-data-api

**What I need**

> I'm working on a C# app that scans Facebook messages for youtube links
> and adds each new video to an existing playlist. If the playlist doesn't exist
> yet, it needs to be created.

**What I have**

I have this code that creates a new playlist:

```
// Create a new, private playlist in the authorized user's channel.
var newPlaylist = new Playlist();
newPlaylist.Snippet = new PlaylistSnippet();
newPlaylist.Snippet.Title = "Test Playlist";
newPlaylist.Snippet.Description = "A playlist created with the YouTube API v3";
newPlaylist.Status = new PlaylistStatus();
newPlaylist.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public";
newPlaylist = await youtubeService.Playlists.Insert(newPlaylist, "snippet,status").ExecuteAsync();
```

but since it's insert, it will always create a new instance of the same requested playlist, on multiple runs. It should be update if the playlist already exists.

This is the code that adds a new video, also insert:

```
try
{
    // Add a video to the newly created playlist.
    var newPlaylistItem = new PlaylistItem();
    newPlaylistItem.Snippet = new PlaylistItemSnippet();
    newPlaylistItem.Snippet.PlaylistId = "PLMl3RyOwPdGlcrBTNYiu1XiNNgqYx6mx8";
    //newPlaylistItem.Snippet.PlaylistId = newPlaylist.Id;
    newPlaylistItem.Snippet.ResourceId = new ResourceId();
    newPlaylistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.Kind = "youtube#video";
    newPlaylistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId = videoId;
    newPlaylistItem = await youtubeService.PlaylistItems.Insert(newPlaylistItem, "snippet").ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Do some logging.
    // Likely doesn't exist anymore, ignore.
}
```

**Question**

> 1. How do I check if a playlist already exists?
> 2. How do I check if a videa was already added?

Comment: What about [getting all playlists](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet#Retrieving_Playlists) of a user and then checking whether specific playlist exists?

Comment: @Gabrielius: Looks promising, I'll look into it! The link itself is version 2.0 though, which is deprecated. Maybe it does still work though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) to access the data:

1. [Playlists: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) - will allow you to list all the playlists of a user
2. [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) - will allow you to list the items in playlist